# Laravel SSL direct with query parameters?

Tags: laravel-4

I currently use:

```
Route::filter('no.ssl', function()
{
    if( Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::to(Request::path(), 302, array(), false);
    }
});
```

The problem comes in with this part:

```
Request::path()
```

If the URL the user was accessing was:

```
example.com/bla?p=1
```

Then it will redirect to:

```
example.com/bla
```

How can I include the query parameters?

I had a look [here](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Http.Request.html) and there is no apparent way to include the query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
Route::filter('force.ssl', function()
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return 
            Redirect::secure(
                Request::path().(empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '' : '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
            );
    }
});

Route::filter('no.ssl', function()
{
    if( Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::to(
            Request::path().(empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '' : '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), 302, array(), false
        );

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated API docs are located here: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/

If you look up the Request class you'll find a `fullUrl()` method which should do what you want.

EDIT: The above was incorrect! This should work but is more verbose. I'd add it as a helper method/function somewhere.

```
if (null !== $qs = $request->getQueryString()) {
    $qs = '?'.$qs;
}
return $request->getBaseUrl().$request->getPathInfo().$qs;
```

Comment: Full URL returns the entire URL, including domain name and HTTP/HTTPS, so it doesn't quite work in this context.

Comment: Silly oversight by me! Edited.